# Bpy get the name of a collection an object belongs to

Tags: python, scripting, objects, collections

For an `if` statement, I want to check if my current object is in collection 'coll'
Here's what I have so far:

```
def GO():
    objects = bpy.data.objects
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.parent==None and obj.type=='MESH' and obj.collection.name('coll'):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your object is in only one collection, you can use:

```py
if obj.users_collection[0].name == "coll":
    print("yes")
```

If your object is present in multiple collections and you want to just check if it is also part of the collection named "coll", you can use:

```py
if "coll" in [c.name for c in obj.users_collection]:
    print("yes")
```

Comment: I suppose you mean to compare against `.name` in the first snippet, I suggested an edit.

Comment: @Ray interesting because I always test my posted code. I wonder how I made that mistake. thanks for the edit. approved.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see it at first aswell. More or less copied the example and noticed the comparisons always failed... :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `collection` member in [`bpy.types.Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html)

instead you need to search the collection for the object:

```py
def is_in_collection(name, obj):
    try:
        col = bpy.data.collections[name]
        for o in col.objects:
            if obj is o:
                return True
        return False
    except KeyError:
        return False
    return False
```

Comment: there is. it is in `obj.users_collection` which is a list of all the collections the object belongs to