The same object in different collections. How to determine which collection contains the selected object (highlighted in blue) in outliner?
The screenshot shows the outliner diagram.
The Cube object is in two different collections - Collection 1, Collection 2.
Using LMB I can select the Cube in Collection 1 and leave the object unselected in Collection 2.
How to use Python to determine the collection in which this object is selected?
Because obj.users_collection produces both collections. And I only need one.
Thank you in advance for any help.


It seems there is a limitation in the python API. But why do you need this? Maybe this is an XY problem? Maybe you can try change the workflow to avoid having it in 2 collections? Not sure.

using the selected object I want to make the parent collection active. a small addon that will do this automatically

maybe this can provide a clue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283705/142292

oh maybe not. did you find an answer?

AFAIK and as far as the python API is concerned this is the same object, and it is selected, I don't think the blue tint hightlight state is available to the API. Happy to be proven wrong as it seems object linking and collection linking suffer from a bit of oversight API-wise. See https://devtalk.blender.org/t/unique-identifier-for-layer-collections/23966
